# Babel and webpack generate files that match my source files structure

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am using babel, and getting some errors, so I'd like to debug with chrome devtools. However when I try to do that, in the Sources panel I only get  two minimified files with eval used, `application.js` and `vendor.bundle.js`. 
Here's how they look:

```
webpackJsonp([0],[
/* 0 */,
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

eval("/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(module) {//! moment.js\n//! version : 2.17.1\n//! authors : Tim Wood, Iskren Chernev, Moment.js contributors\n//! license : MIT\n//! momentjs.com\n\n;(function (global, ....
/***/ },
/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

"use strict";
eval("\"use strict\";\n\nexports.__esModule = true;\n\nexports.default = function (instance, Constructor) {\n  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {\n    throw new TypeError(\"Cannot call a class as a functio...
/***/ },...
```

So I can't debug that. Here is my configuration for base:

```
// Common Webpack configuration used by webpack.config.development and webpack.config.production

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/client'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/scripts'),
      path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/assets'),
      path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/javascripts'),
      'node_modules'
    ],
    alias: {
      models: path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/javascripts/models')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.scss']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'  // fetch API
    }),
    // Shared code
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filename: 'js/vendor.bundle.js',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    // ["import", { libraryName: "antd", style: "css" }]
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // JavaScript / ES6
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/javascripts'),
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {...},
      // Fonts
      {...}
    ]
  },
  postcss: function () {...}
};
```

And my development config:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('./webpack.config.base');
const path = require('path');


const GLOBALS = {
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
  },
  __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'true'))
};

module.exports = merge(config, {
  debug: true,
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    application: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'development'
    ],
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-redux', 'react-router', 'react-router-redux', 'redux']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS)
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // Sass, CSS
      {...}, {...}
    ]
  }
});
```